# Camera2 Library not giving default capture sound on picture taken in android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, image-capture

everyone ! 
I have searched about the capture sound in new Camera2 Library but i did't find it. I need to play capture sound when image is taken. As in old hardware.camera there is shutterCallBack which we can use to play sound. if any one know how to do that please thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In Camera2 api still exist a callback method that you can use for play shutter sound

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html

> CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.onCaptureStarted

added in API level 21
void onCaptureStarted (CameraCaptureSession session, 
                CaptureRequest request, 
                long timestamp, 
                long frameNumber)
This method is called when the camera device has started capturing the output image for the request, at the beginning of image exposure, or when the camera device has started processing an input image for a reprocess request.

For a regular capture request, this callback is invoked right as the capture of a frame begins, so it is the most appropriate time for playing a shutter sound, or triggering UI indicators of capture.

The request that is being used for this capture is provided, along with the actual timestamp for the start of exposure. For a reprocess request, this timestamp will be the input image's start of exposure which matches the result timestamp field of the TotalCaptureResult that was used to create the reprocess request. This timestamp matches the timestamps that will be included in the result timestamp field, and in the buffers sent to each output Surface. These buffer timestamps are accessible through, for example, Image.getTimestamp() or getTimestamp(). The frame number included is equal to the frame number that will be included in getFrameNumber().

For the simplest way to play a shutter sound camera shutter or a video recording start/stop sound, see the MediaActionSound class.

The default implementation of this method does nothing.